# What does directory permission 02777 do?

Tags: unix, file-permissions

Found the following PHP code today:

```
mkdir($directory, 02777);

chmod($directory, 02777);
```

I understand the PHP, but not first part of those numbers. The 777 part is clear, and if I have understood correctly the 0 just means it's octal. But what does the 2 in there do?

Also, if I changed it to 02640, would the 2 still do whatever it does, or does it change according to what comes after it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This octal digit is made up of `setuid`, `setgid` and `sticky` bits, all of which have comparatively complex effects.

The `2` sets the `setgid` flag. When present on a directory, all files created within it will inherit its group, instead of the creating user's primary group.

More on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setgid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories).